# Why is flex item overflowing container in mobile version?

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout, flexbox

I am new to CSS and HTML, right now I am trying out FlexBox. Here is my code for the layout. Can anyone please explain to me why my second div (`.rightContainer`) leaves its parent? I already tried to delete the height, but it didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FlexBox Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="leftContainer">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightContainer">
            <div class="banner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pvvqwrb4/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mobile layout (`@media(max-width: 600px)`), the `.rightContainer` flex item overflows the flex `.container` because:

1. You have `.container` limited to `height: 800px`.

   So the first adjustment is to switch `height` to `min-height`:

   ```
   .container {
        border: 10px solid lightcoral;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 70%;
        min-height: 800px; /* adjusted */
        display: flex;
   }
   ```

   ---
2. You've applied `flex: 1 1 0` to `.rightContainer`.

   This tells the flex item to be flexible within the available space in the container. However, with `height: 800px` on the container and `flex: 0 1 auto` on `.leftContainer`, *there is no remaining space in the container*.

   So instead of `flex: 1 1 0` try `flex: 1 1 auto`, which sizes the flex item based on content.

   ```
   .rightContainer {
         background: peachpuff;
         margin: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
         flex: 1 1 auto; /* adjusted */
   }
   ```

   [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pvvqwrb4/5/)

   *Quick summary:*

   - `flex: 1 1 0` sizes the item based on the free space in the flex container.
   - `flex: 1 1 auto` sizes the item based on content width or height properties.

   For more details see the flexbox spec: [***7.1.1. Common Values of `flex`***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).